# How can I make a postgresql and postgis enabled image pgrouting enabled?

Tags: docker

I need to create a `postgresql` image that is `postGIS` enabled. Luckily for me, an image was already created **[HERE](https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/~/dockerfile/)**.

Now, what I would like to do, precisely, is make this image `pgRouting` enabled. How can I go about doing this ?